# Python time to hex list

Tags: python, hex, raspberry-pi, pic, spi

I wish to send out a data telegram onto the SPI port of a Raspberry Pi (running Python 2.7.3) containing time data and some hex characters for decoding on the receiving end (a PIC microcontroller).
In the past I used the serial output port of the Pi and that worked like a charm, using the imported serial module.

```
serialport.write(chr(10))
serialport.write(chr(20))
serialport.write(chr(1))
serialport.write(chr(255))
ser_out = time.strftime("%H$%M$%d$%w$%a$%A$%m$%b$%B$%y", localtime())
serialport.write(ser_out.encode("utf8"))
```

The imported spidev module however requires the information to be in a list containing hex values.

```
spi.writebytes([0x10,0x20,0x01,0xFF,0x32,0x31,0x24 ...
```

Question is: 
How can I convert from a cobbled-together string and hex to a **list** of hex only values?

I tried a few thing such as the list method, map and .encode("hex") but i am only started wetting my feat into the pool of python's recently :).

Comment: To add to what muddyfish wrote in python the literal 0x10 is literally (no pun intended) the number we write as 16 in decimal. If you enter `0x10` in the interpreter it'll print 16 as the result. So spi.writebytes([16]) will have exactly the same result as spi.writebytes([0x10]).

Comment: Make sure this `%H$%M$%d$%w$%a$%A$%m$%b$%B$%y` gives you a readable string with time info. Say comma terminated. Then do `commaTerminatedTimeString.split(',')`, this will give a list of substrings separated by ','. Then convert to hex. Give it a shot.

Comment: How does the data you want to send looks like? Is it a string containing hex numbers? Could you provide an example.

Comment: The data string would contain (all in hex)  4 bytes for addressing, 3 bytes of register pointers followed by the time data in which each element (such as hour, minute, name of the day, ...) is separated by a $ (0x24), closed by a 0xFF.

Comment: Did you overridden `chr`? For example `chr(10)` = `\n` (hex: `0x0A`) and not `0x10` (as the first list element). Same thing with the others. Also according to your last comment, `serialport.write(chr(255))` should be moved at the end.